# Glowing text in IE (DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow) and antialiasing

Tags: webfonts, css

I'm trying to create a glowing text which will work correctly in Internet Explorer.

I have this text-shadow declaration:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 4px White;
```

and for IE, I added this:

```
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color='White') progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Strength=5, Color=#ffffff)";
```

It works, but it turns off the text antialiasing, so it looks really ugly - compare these two images (Chrome vs IE9):

[image] [image]

Do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe this gets things looking a tad more modern:

```
<font style="display: block; filter: glow(Color=white, Strength=$2) 
blur(add=false, direction=0, strength=1) 
blur(add=false, direction=180, strength=1) 
blur(add=false, direction=270, strength=1) 
blur(add=false, direction=90, strength=1">Novinky</font>
```

basically, this is a sort of pseudo antialiazation
the glow is applied first, then blurred by 1 pixel in 4 directions (U,D,L,R)
(even blurrs the glow itself)

test page:
http://tcll5850.proboards.com/thread/178/post-glow-plugin-darkpikachu

reference page:
http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/visual-filters.shtml